How many numbers in the range 0.001 .. 0.999 cannot be represented as Floating Point numbers?
Everybody knows, that not all numbers can be represented as Floating Point numbers. For example 0.1 has no exact Floating Point representation.
There is already the question, How many values can be represented in a given range by a float? But that question talks more about big number. It is quite obvious, that not all such big numbers can be represented as floating point numbers. There must be gaps.
I am interested in small numbers. Let's say we look at decimal numbers with 3 digits from 0.001 to 0.999. How many of them cannot be represented accurately as Floating Point numbers? Can we create a list of them?
There is a similar question, how many numbers between 0-1 can a 32bit floating point represent? But that question asks how many Floating Point numbers exist, at all? That is not my question. I want to know how well these numbers match to the decimal numbers 0.001 to 0.999.
I know, there is a way to find out if a number is representable as a Floating Point number (What types of numbers are representable in binary floating-point?). But that is a bit theoretical. Couldn't we just try out all these numbers if they are representable. I think, this would be more handy for most practical persons.
I tried to write a small C code for this. I placed a constant like 0.1. But when I then in my C program compare if that constant is really 0.1, it tells me that both values are identical. Of course they are identical, because the value, against which I compare has the same representation error.

If you want to avoid decimal to double issues, use 0x notation as in 0x7.0p-3 for 0.875.

About 25% of all double are in the [0 ... 1) range, %25 in the [1.0 ... inf] range and the other 50% are the negatives.

Presumably you mean binary floating-point, and with a reasonable size for the significand and exponent. (“Floating-point” only means that the value is scaled, so that the radix point “floats” as directed by the exponent. It does not mean two is used as the base for the digits. Floating-point can use decimal, in which case all three-digit decimal numbers from 0.001 to 0.999 are representable.)
The only three-decimal-digit numbers representable in binary floating-point in the interval from 0.001 to 0.999 are .125, .250, .375, .500, .625, .750, and .875.
These are all multiples of ⅛, so they are representable in binary floating-point as f•2−3 with f = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7. (Some of these are not normalized; 2•2−3 is also representable as 1•2−2.) Other multiples of ⅛ are outside the interval.
Consider any three-decimal-digit number in this interval. It equals x•10−3 for an integer x, 0 < x < 1000. To be representable in binary floating-point, we would have x•10−3 = f•2e for some integers F and e. Then x = f•2e•103 = f•2e+3•53. Observe that e may be negative, even less than −3, in which case it can cancel some factors of 2 in f, but this cannot remove the factors of 5 induced by 53. Therefore, x must be a multiple of 53 = 125. All such x in 0 < x < 1000 are 125, 250, 375, 500, 625, 750, and 875, giving us the numbers above.


How many [decimal] numbers cannot be represented as Floating Point numbers?

The short and perhaps surprising answer is, "Almost all of them".
Floating point is not designed for representing decimal fractions.  If you're worried about all the decimal fractions that can't be represented precisely using binary floating point, you may be looking at your problem the wrong way.

I tried to write a small C code for this. I placed a constant like 0.1. But [...] it tells me that both values are identical. Of course they are identical, because the value, against which I compare has the same representation error.

Right.  Here's a way to do it.  This program first constructs strings which are the decimal fractions you're interested in, 0.000 up to 0.999.  Then it converts them to floating-point using atof, and then it converts them back to decimal using sprintf.  Finally, it checks to see if the two strings are identical.  As written, it prints only the ones that are representable.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void strip0(char *buf);

int main()
{
    int i;
    double d;
    char buf[10];
    char buf2[30];
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "0.%03d", i);
        d = atof(buf);
        sprintf(buf2, "%.25f", d);
        strip0(buf);
        strip0(buf2);
        if(strcmp(buf, buf2) == 0)
            printf("representable: %s\n", buf);
    }
}

One wrinkle is that when the constructed string is, say, "0.500", that gets "printed" back out by sprintf as something more like "0.5000000000", which is a different string.  So it's necessary to strip trailing 0's before comparing, using this auxiliary function:
void strip0(char *buf)
{
    int i;
    for(i = strlen(buf) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(buf[i] == '0')
            buf[i] = '\0';
        else    break;
    }
}

Anyway, when I run this program, it prints:
representable: 0.
representable: 0.125
representable: 0.25
representable: 0.375
representable: 0.5
representable: 0.625
representable: 0.75
representable: 0.875

You will notice that this is more or less the same list Eric provided in his answer.
To see what's going on with all the ones that aren't representable, you can make this change:
        if(strcmp(buf, buf2) != 0)
            printf("not representable: %s != %s\n", buf, buf2);

When I run it this way the first 10 lines it prints are:
not representable: 0.001 != 0.0010000000000000000208167
not representable: 0.002 != 0.0020000000000000000416334
not representable: 0.003 != 0.00300000000000000006245
not representable: 0.004 != 0.0040000000000000000832667
not representable: 0.005 != 0.0050000000000000001040834
not representable: 0.006 != 0.0060000000000000001249001
not representable: 0.007 != 0.0070000000000000001457168
not representable: 0.008 != 0.0080000000000000001665335
not representable: 0.009 != 0.0089999999999999993199884
not representable: 0.01 != 0.0100000000000000002081668

You can pretty easily change this program to find the representable  4 or 5-digit decimal fractions too.  (If you do, you'll find they're all multiples of 1/16 or 1/32.  Binary fractions are like English rulers: they're all about halves and quarters and eighths and sixteenths and thirty-seconds; they're no good for measuring tenths or hundredths or thousandths.)
